# Even and odd side margin

Tags: margins

I would like odd and even side margins in my document and I would like ask how could I set my document to automatically switching the margins. (And it would be important to keep the settings of the text).

This is my code right now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `[twopage]` option of your documentclass? 
`\documentclass[twoside]{article}`

Comment: Yes but when I try this it messes up my document, and I can't see any changes of the margins.

Comment: There are a huge number of answers to this question, but we can't know what will be useful without seeing a minimal example of your document and some suggestions about what margins you want. The best answer will likely be `memoir`.

Comment: My request is actually very simple becouse what I want is to placing alternately left and right the text which is centered right now (becouse it will be printed) but without changing the font size, font type, etc. This picture shows what I would like to reach : http://i.stack.imgur.com/JzvuX.png, but with the same margin.

Comment: `[twoside]` option does exactly this, if you have a case where it is not working show a small complete example document that shows the problem.

Comment: your example isn't really large enough to show any problem with changing the first line to `\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{article}` which should be the answer.